PHPUnit ignore deprecation in dependencies
I’m testing my packages for compatibility with PHP 8.4.1. However, some dependencies trigger deprecation warnings. Is there a way to configure PHPUnit to report deprecation warnings only for my package and ignore those from dependencies? In other words, ignore all deprecations within the vendor dir?

Sebastian Bergmann, the creator of PHPUnit answered the question on GitHub. This is his answer.
Yes, this is possible. Unfortunately, not everything that is possible is already documented (well enough), but some documentation is available here.
For the most common use case, you want to have this in your phpunit.xml configuration file:
<source ignoreIndirectDeprecations="true" restrictNotices="true" restrictWarnings="true">
    <include>
        <directory>src</directory>
    </include>
</source>


<source><include><directory>src</directory></include></source> tells PHPUnit that you consider only code in the src directory as your own code (first-party code) (as well as your test code)
Everything else, for example code in vendor, is considered "not your own code" (third-party code)
ignoreIndirectDeprecations="true" tells PHPUnit that you are only interested in E_DEPRECATED and E_USER_DEPRECATED that are triggered in your own code from your own code
restrictNotices="true" tells PHPUnit that you are only interested in E_NOTICE and E_USER_NOTICE triggered in your own code
restrictWarnings="true" tells PHPUnit that you are only interested in E_WARNING and E_USER_WARNING triggered in your own code

